# Search for value in xml file bash script

Tags: xml, bash, parsing, find

I have xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>project100</artifactId>
<versioning>
  <latest>1.2.1-black</latest>
  <release>1.2.1-black</release>
 <versions>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <version>1.0.0-black</version>
   <version>1.0.2</version>
   <version>1.0.1</version>
   <version>1.2.0</version>
   <version>1.2.1-black</version>
  </versions>
 </versionsing>
</metadata>
```

And also I have a variable like: $ID=1.0.2 and I want to check if this id exist in my xml file.
I try something like this:

```
'cat ///metadata/versioning/version/text()' | xmllint --shell $content | grep -v "^/ >"
```

where $contenet is my xml file but this shows mi something like this:

```
warning: failed to load external entity "<version>1.0.0</version>
```

for each entity from xml file. I have no idea how to do this. I kind of noobie in bash scripting

Comment: `versioning` or `versionsing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `$content` contains the *contents* of your file, whereas the tool you are using expects you to pass the *name* of the file. It is treating each "word" of your XML (like `<version>1.0.0</version>`) as a path to a file and cannot find one, so is complaining.

I also notice that you're using `--shell`, then having to use grep to remove the prompt. You can avoid this by using `--xpath` directly.

I would suggest trying something like this:

```
echo "$content" | xmllint --xpath '//metadata/versioning/versions/version/text()' -
```

Or if you have the name of the file to hand, then just do this:

```
xmllint --xpath '//metadata/versioning/versions/version/text()' file.xml
```

I assume that `versionsing` was a typo, so I changed it to `versioning` in the XPath. I also added the missing part `versions/` (thanks [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba)).

Given that you're trying to filter to a specific version, I guess you want something like this:

```
$ id=1.0.0
$ xmllint --xpath "//metadata/versionsing/versions/version[text() = '$id']/text()" file.xml
1.0.0
```

To find out if a given version exists, you could do this:

```
id=1.2.3
xpath="//metadata/versionsing/versions/version[text() = '$id']"
if xmllint --xpath "$xpath" file.xml 2>/dev/null
then
    echo "version $id found"
else
    echo "version $id not found"
fi
```

Comment: Note that the Xpath expressions is missing one step: `versions/`.

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you if ID value is present in the XML file:

```
$ grep -q $ID file.xml && echo exists
```

**EDIT**
Excluding partial matches:

```
$ grep ">${ID}<" file.xml && echo exists
```

Comment: Oops, it says version `2.1-b` exists.